# i want to create Fragment Tab Bar.but it gives error?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-tabs

My Code Is here, but it shows on emulator screen unfortunately your application stopped.

Main. XML

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Main Activity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
Context context=this;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(context, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1"),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2"),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3"),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
}

}
```

FragmentTab.Java

```
public class FragmentTab extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText(this.getTag() + " Content");
    return v;
}
}
```

fragment_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

but when i run this code it give RunTime Error. m totally confused about this any body can help me?

Comment: please post the error that you see in the Logcat...

Comment: post your stack trace here

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(2045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.ausichlid, PID: 2045
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ausichlid/com.example.ausichlid.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
  at

Answer (score 0):

I think your ids are wrong in xml. Your `TabHost` must be `@android:id/tabhost` (android.R.id.tabhost) and your `TabWidget` must be `@android:id/tabs` (android.R.id.tabs)

See this simple example [Creating a Tab Layout with FragmentTabHost and Fragments](http://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah yes, I was also going to shoot from the hip and guess that he was trying to use the wrong ID here:  `mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);`